# New variable in With structure appear as global, and many other strange things I don't understand

Tags: scoping, variable-definitions

I thought I know `With` and `Module` until I see this [example](https://wolfram.com/xid/09xqjsod67a2on60bzz20u-xgr) on Wolfram Documentation.

Below is a demo code:

```
Clear["*"];
With[{x = a}, x = 5;]
a (* Oupput new value: 5 *)
Clear["*"];
a = 8
With[{x = a}, x = 5;]
a (* Oupput old value: 8 *)
```

I always though the `x` in the **first `With` structure** is guaranteed to be a constant(`With`'s main function). To my surprise, Not only the `x`'s value is changed, it also give the global variable `a` a new value! What's more strange is that after the global `a` is already defined, like what it is the case in the **second `With` structure**, the same `With` expression cannot affect `a`'s value anymore!

Things are a little more understandable with `Module`:

```
Clear["*"];
Module[{x = a}, x = 5;]
a (* Output undefined symbol: a *)
Clear["*"];
a = 8;
Module[{x = a}, x = 5;]
a (* Oupput old value: 8 *)
```

Can anyone please explain to me how this happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is expected behavior, although perhaps confusing at first; it is the power of `With` :-)

`With` will inject values into held expressions, so it will inject the value `a` for `x` everywhere inside it, and particularly *before* the `Set` expression is evaluated.

Look at the results of [`Trace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Trace.html) for your first `With` expression:

```
Trace@With[{x = a}, x = 5;]

(* Out: {With[{x = a}, x = 5;], a = 5;, {a = 5, 5}, Null} *)
```

When you write `With[{x = a}, x = 5;]` this becomes `a = 5`, which then assigns the value 5 to global variable `a`.

Comment: Then how come the second With statement didn't modified the value of 'a' to 5?

Comment: @MurphyNg because `a` already had a value, so x=5 would become 8=5, which doesn’t work and throws an error. Did you not see the error message “Set: can not assign to raw object 8”?

Comment: I missed it. The way Wolfram language works really is different from other programming language. It's damn hard making the transit to thinking variable assignment as expression substitution rather than stuff like memory address and so on.

Comment: @MurphyNg Agreed. It really is a different paradigm, and `With` is perhaps one of the weirder ones out there.